# Elm divide subscription?

Tags: elm

I'm playing with Elm and WebRTC, so I made a listen port which gets some messages from js:

```
type alias Message = 
    { channel : String
    , data : String
    }
port listen : (Message -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

Now I would like to be able to divide the messages to different parts of my app. For instance, the chat uses the "chat" channel, while the game logic uses "game".

Is it possible to create a `listenTo String` subscription that filters out the messages with the correct channel (only returning the data)? Or perhaps a different way of doing it?

### Update:

What I currently have, is something like this:

In my main.elm I have an update that looks like this. It can receive messages (from rtc) itself, and send messages for chat to it. (I would later add a "ForGame" then too)

```
type Msg = Received WebRTC.Message | ForChat Chat.Msg

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Received message -> 
            let 
                _ = Debug.log ("Received message on \"" ++ message.channel ++ "\": " ++ message.data)
            in
                ( model
                , Cmd.none
                )
        ForChat msg ->
            let 
                (chatModel, chatCmd) = Chat.update msg model.chat
            in  
                ({ model | chat = chatModel}, Cmd.map ForChat chatCmd)
```

Then I have subscriptions that combines all my subscriptions:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = 
    Sub.batch 
        [ WebRTC.listen Received
        , Sub.map ForChat <| Chat.subscriptions model.chat
        ]
```

In Chat.elm I have a similar structure, with an update that handles it's messages. The subscription of the chat listens to all messages from WebRTC, but filters only the ones with channel chat:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = WebRTC.listen forChatMessages

forChatMessages : WebRTC.Message -> Msg
forChatMessages webrtcMessage =
    if webrtcMessage.channel == "chat"
    then
        let
            message = decodeMessage webrtcMessage.data
        in
            case message of
                Ok msg -> Receive msg
                Err error -> Debug.log ("Received unreadable message on chat channel \"" ++ toString webrtcMessage.data ++ "\" with error \"" ++ error ++ "\"") Ignore
    else
        Ignore
```

(Ignore is a Msg for chat, which just does nothing `case msg of Ignore -> (model, Cmd.none)`. `decodeMessage` uses a decoder to decode a message `decodeMessage : String -> Result String Message`.)

I'm quite happy with this, because this way all logic for chat is in Chat.elm. So main.elm doesn't need to know what channels chat is using. Chat just follows the standard structure (Msg, update, view, subscriptions) and main forwards everything.

The only thing that's still not great, is that in Chat.elm I have the `forChatMessages` function. Used like: `subscriptions model = WebRTC.listen forChatMessages`. I would like to make this more reuseable, so it would become something like:

```
subscriptions model = WebRTC.listen for "chat" decodeMessage Receive Ignore
```

It would then be reusable by the game:

```
subscriptions model = WebRTC.listen for "game" decodeGameInfo UpdateInfo Ignore
```

### Update 2:

I managed to generalize the `forChatMessages` function into:

```
for : String -> (String -> Result String d) -> (d -> msg) -> msg -> Message -> msg
for channel decoder good bad webrtcMessage =
    if 
        webrtcMessage.channel == channel
    then
        let
            decoded = decoder webrtcMessage.data
        in
            case decoded of
                Ok data -> good data
                Err error -> Debug.log ("Failed decoding message on " ++ channel ++ "channel \"" ++ toString webrtcMessage.data ++ "\" with error \"" ++ error ++ "\"") bad
    else
        bad
```

So I think I found the solution myself. Unless someones has comments on this. Perhaps there is a cleaner/nicer/better way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself, and added it to the original question.

For clarity, this is the short version:

In my main.elm:

```
type Msg = Received WebRTC.Message | ForChat Chat.Msg

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Received message -> 
            let 
                _ = Debug.log ("Received message on \"" ++ message.channel ++ "\": " ++ message.data)
            in
                ( model
                , Cmd.none
                )
        ForChat msg ->
            let 
                (chatModel, chatCmd) = Chat.update msg model.chat
            in  
                ({ model | chat = chatModel}, Cmd.map ForChat chatCmd)


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = 
    Sub.batch 
        [ WebRTC.listen Received
        , Sub.map ForChat <| Chat.subscriptions model.chat
        ]
```

In Chat.elm:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = WebRTC.listen <| for "game" decodeGameInfo UpdateInfo Ignore
```

In WebRTC.elm:

```
type alias Message = 
    { channel : String
    , data : String
    }
port listen : (Message -> msg) -> Sub msg

for : String -> (String -> Result String d) -> (d -> msg) -> msg -> Message -> msg
for channel decoder good bad webrtcMessage =
    if 
        webrtcMessage.channel == channel
    then
        let
            decoded = decoder webrtcMessage.data
        in
            case decoded of
                Ok data -> good data
                Err error -> Debug.log ("Failed decoding message on " ++ channel ++ "channel \"" ++ toString webrtcMessage.data ++ "\" with error \"" ++ error ++ "\"") bad
    else
        bad
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following `Msg` definition:

```elm
type Msg
    = Listen Message
    | GameChannel String
    | ChatChannel String
```

Your `update` function could then act upon the `channel` value and call `update` again with the correct channel, ignoring all `channel` values except for `"game"` and `"chat"`:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Listen message ->
            case message.channel of
                "game" ->
                    update (GameChannel message.data) model

                "chat" ->
                    update (ChatChannel message.data) model

                _ ->
                    model ! []

        GameChannel data ->
            ...

        ChatChannel data ->
            ...
```

Your subscription function would look something like this:

```elm
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    listen Listen
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I was doing, and wasn't really what I meant. I update my original question with more info. I have since changed the system to something for to my liking, but still need help refining it.